# Question regarding quadratic residue

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

I am new to this and confused myself, but will try my best to explain the problem clearly.

> An integer $a$ is a quadratic residue with respect to prime p if $a \equiv x^2 \mod{p}$ for some integer $x$.

Here are my questions:

1. Does $p$ need to be prime? I ask because definition from [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticResidue.html) doesn't requires it to be so. And from Euler's criterion:

   - If $a^\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv 1 \mod{p}$, it means $a$ is a quadratic
     residue module $p$.
   - If $a^\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv -1 \mod{p}$, it means $a$ is a not a quadratic residue module $p$.

   So if $p$ is not a prime then $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ won't even be an integer. And so according to me it should be odd prime.
2. Should $0\lt x \lt p$ be true? What if we have $a\equiv x^2\mod{p}$, and $x \gt p$? The thing is I tried finding such $x$ by pen, but always found that there is always a $y \lt p$ such that $a\equiv y^2\mod{p}$. Is this always true? And how can we prove it?

Comment: Quadratic residues are also defined for composite numbers. Euler's criterion deals in fact basically with odd primes. But $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$ can also be true for composite numbers (see Carmichael numbers or Fermat-pseudoprimes)

Comment: You can replace $x$ by its residue mod $p$ without changing $x^2$ modulo $p$

Comment: It's just convenient to start  exploring quadratic residues in $\mathbb Z_p$. Also, in $\mathbb Z_p$, we study $\bar x$ not $x$. In that case, $0 < x < p$ is irrelevant.

Comment: @Peter "You can replace $x$ by its residue $\mod p$ without changing $x^2 \mod p$". I can't understand this, can you please give an example?

Comment: @stevengregory excuse me for my ignorance, but what do you mean by: "we study  $\bar x$  not $x$".

Comment: For example $78^2\equiv 1^2=1\mod 11$ because of $78\equiv 1\mod 11$, so you can replace $78$ by $1$ , which is the residue of $78$ modulo $11$

Comment: @Peter Thank you.

Comment: What steven means is that $\bar x$ is the equivalence class of all numbers having some given residue modulo $n$. Usually the number from $0$ to $n-1$ that gives the desired residue is chosen as a representant. Sometimes however, the smallest absolute value is chosen, for example -2 mod 5 instead of 3 mod 5 because this can simplify calculations drastically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the *definition* of a quadratic residue, the modulus doesn't have to be a prime number. However, the *law of quadratic reciprocity* is valid for primes.

For you second question, we usually choose $x<p$ for convenience. This is no loss of generality, since if $x\equiv x'\mod p$, then $x$ is a square $\bmod p$ if and only if $x'$ is. Computations with the *Legendre symbol* relies on this property and the fact this symbol is *multiplicative*.